# Comparing row value with text fields to row of untyped string literals in CASE

Tags: postgresql, casting, case

I found a neat way on stackoverflow of handling multi-variable `case` statement using ROW values. It's great how clean it looks ...

However, I get errors directly comparing a row value made of 2 table columns of type `text` with a row made of string literals.

I've used a workaround with a function `spTup('Deposit', '' )` which works but may be slower. The other way that works is to explicitly cast the string literals to `text`, but that creates a lot of visual clutter.

**Questions:**

1. Why can't Postgres deduce that the string literals should be treated
   as `text` type?
2. Why can Postgres deduce the type of the string literal in single element row, but not the row with 2 elements?
3. I thought I was getting a handle on Postgres type handling, but I don't quite get this scenario, can anyone explain?
4. Is there any other approach which minimises visual clutter?

I'm using Postgres 10.1 on localhost and 9.6.6 in test & production server.

**Test setup:**

```
create table if not exists tblTest ( SeqID serial, EventType text, EventResult text, Amt decimal );
truncate table tblTest;
insert into tblTest( EventType, EventResult, Amt )
values ( 'Withdrawal', '', 1.11 ), ('Deposit', '', 2.22 ), ('Deposit', 'succeeded', 3.33 ), ('Deposit', 'failed', 4.44 );

create or replace function spTup( p_1 text, p_2 text ) 
returns record as $func$
    select ( p_1, p_2 );
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE; 


-- Runs without error (using single element tuple)
select SeqID, EventType, case ( EventType ) when ( 'Deposit' ) then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

-- ERROR: cannot compare dissimilar column types text and unknown at record column 1
select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, case ( EventType, EventResult ) 
when ( 'Deposit', '' ) then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

-- Runs without error -- visually the cleanest apart from using spTup function
select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, case ( EventType, EventResult )::text 
when ( 'Deposit', '' )::text then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

-- Runs without error
select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, case ( EventType, EventResult ) 
when ( 'Deposit'::text, ''::text ) then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, case ( EventType, EventResult ) 
when spTup( 'Deposit', '' ) then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

-- ERROR: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented
select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, case ( EventType, EventResult ) 
when '( "Deposit", "" )' then Amt else 9.999 end
from tblTest;

-- Just out of interest
select ( 'Deposit', '' ), ( 'Deposit'::text, ''::text );
/**
    row             row
    (Deposit,"")    (Deposit,"")
**/

select SeqID, EventType, EventResult, ( EventType, EventResult )
from tblTest;
/** 
    seqid   eventtype   eventresult     row
    1       Withdrawal                  (Withdrawal,"")
    2       Deposit                     (Deposit,"")
    3       Deposit     succeeded       (Deposit,succeeded)
    4       Deposit     failed          (Deposit,failed)
**/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be **a restriction of the "simple" or "switched" [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)** you are using.
The alternative syntax variant of `CASE` works without explicit cast:

```
select SeqID, EventType, EventResult
     , CASE WHEN (EventType, EventResult) = ('Deposit', '') THEN amt ELSE 9.999 END
from tblTest;
```

As long as you have a single case to test, this variant even *"minimises visual clutter"*. Two additional characters, but easier to read (IMHO). For multiple cases, the "switched" variant would seem preferable, though.

The different behavior obviously results from a different workflow in the "simple" `CASE`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

> The first ***`expression`*** is computed, then compared to each of the ***`value`***
>   expressions in the `WHEN` clauses until one is found that is equal to it.

The code path for the simple *expression - value* comparison tries less hard to resolve data types - and fails for anonymous [**row values**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). Feels like a shortcoming in the implementation. One might expect the same behavior for both variants - and file a bug report.

But the behavior has been like that since at least Postgres 8.4 (and is the same in pg 11):

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb1f493d5faf61ed260a755cf6802aa6)*

Probably very few people had similar ideas with untyped row values in a switched `CASE` so far.

---

Leaves your question:

> 2. Why can Postgres deduce the type of the string literal in single element row, but not the row with 2 elements?

Answer: because row values with a single element (`(foo)`) are simplified to their single element (`foo`) when evaluating expression almost everywhere in Postgres. So this:

```
CASE (eventtype) WHEN ('Deposit') THEN ...
```

is effectively simplified to:

```
CASE  eventtype  WHEN  'Deposit'  THEN ...
```